# Push existing folder to GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-commit

In Gitlab project from the instructions, they tell how to add an existing_folder to Git repository.
But after I press `git commit` the console open a vim.

Then how can I go to the last one `git push -u origin master` and push my repository to gitlab.

```
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin [remote url]
git add .
git commit
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: I am surprised to see 4 upvotes to this. The OP doesn't seem to have read the fundamentals of git in the first place.

Comment: They don't understand the behavior of git, so they're asking on a site designed for code questions. This question is of an introductory level for git, but it is a good SO question: They have something they don't understand, the answer to their question is not easy to find with the wording they have, and they provided an example of the directions they are trying to follow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command `git commit` launches your default command line text editor because a commit needs a message describing what is happening in it. There are two ways to add this message:

1. When the editor (vim) is launched, write a commit message in the editor, then save and close the file. This message will now be stored with the commit. Exiting without saving the file will cancel the commit.
2. Use the command `git commmit -m "Commit message here"`, which allows you add a short commit message in the quotes without launching the editor.

A commit message can be anything, but [here is an article if you want to go in depth on what should be in a message and how to format it](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/). Sometimes I use the full text editor to write a complex message, sometimes I just need a quick note and use the inline command with the `-m` flag.

Want to change the default editor git uses for commit messages? You're in luck! Simply add it to your git config like this: `git config --global core.editor "nano"`. Now commit messages will be opened in nano, or whatever editor command you put in this config command.

Comment: Maybe configuring the editor first `git config --global core.editor <your-fav-editor>` and then commiting with `git commit` without the `-m` flag can help with cleaner commits. This is because user can write a commit message in their favorite editor instead of terminal itself.

Answer (score 5):

Change git commit to

```
git commit -m "insert commit message here"
```

The `-m` flag adds as a commit message whatever you enter in the quotation marks. The vim opens because the message is missing.